# How to login in by HTTPS post request in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-8

I have scenario where my app has to login in by specifying username and password. After successful login I am going to show user all contents.

For example user wants to see https://login.live.com inbox item.  Where user will enter his username and pass in my application’s input filed instead of https://login.live.com . Then application will signed him and show his email inbox.

For this purpose I have to use WebView class to host html content. But I cannot just bring the login page directly to user for logging purpose. So I have to sign the user programmatically then show him all content by WebView class.

Thus I thought it should be possible to use https post request to sign first then use same https session. I might be wrong, there could be other way for windows phone 8. I don’t know right api for windows phone 8. So could you please suggest how can I achieve this goal by using windows phone 8 API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I gave an example of live mail access because it have to go throw https. Sorry for confusion. I don't want to do anything with email at all. It is an internal server which usages https singin before it shows any stuff inside it. it is working fine throw pc web browser as well as mobile browser. But I have some extra requirement to fulfill so I have to make a mobile app. First of I have to sign into the secure server to meet other requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do with windows 8 API because if you want do a client mail(like thunderbird) you must use POP3, IMAP protocls for receveing mails and SMTP protocol for sending mails.

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/) you can find a good library(with references) that implement POP3 protocol

And [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/301836/Simple-SMTP-E-Mail-Sender-in-Csharp-Console-applic) you can find an example about the use of SMTP

Comment: Well, I gave an example of live mail access because it have to go throw https. Sorry for confusion. I don't want to do anything with email at all. It is an internal server which usages https singin before it shows any stuff inside it. it is working fine throw pc web browser as well as mobile browser. But I have some extra requirement to fulfill so I have to make a mobile app. First of I have to sign into the secure server to meet other requirement.

Comment: So correct me if I' wrong: you want do a loin to xYz.com site and then receive the information about it. Correct?